# does UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit scale image everytime leaving transparent area around

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, image-resizing

I am having a hard time understanding how the UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit works . I am working on app in which i want that the image should be redrawn in such a way that there must be blank area around the image and the image must be set in the center of the image view.
My main concern is that will the UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit scale image leaving an transparent area around (in every case) or do i need to redraw image programmatically.

Comment: Go to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html) , You will get your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

If the background of the `UIImageView` that contains that image is white, then the areas not filled by the image will be white in that view.